# Unable to implement Second Level Cache in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, sessionfactory, second-level-cache

## **While learning and implementing Second Level Cache for the first time, i included the below necessary dependencies in my pom.xml file**

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

## **In the hibernate configuration-XML File, i included the below necessary properties:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">abhijayesh</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name ="format_sql">true</property>
        
        <property name = "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory</property>

    <mapping class = "com.spring.hibernate.Student"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

[hibernate configuration-XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA9rL.png)

## **The mapping class 'Student' looks like:**

```
package com.spring.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import jakarta.persistence.Cacheable;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    
    private Certificate certi;
```

***further the class Student.java also includes:***
*-all getters and setters
-default constructor
-parameterized constructor
-toString method*

## **In my Main Driver class, I've implemented SessionFactory too**

```
SessionFactory factory = 
new Configuration().configure("hibernateconfig.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        Session session1 = factory.openSession();

        Student std1 = session1.get(Student.class, 320);
        System.out.println(std1);

        session1.close();

        Session session2 = factory.openSession();

        Student std2 = session2.get(Student.class, 320);
        System.out.println(std2);

        session2.close();

        factory.close();
```

As an output, I was expecting that the hibernate will hit the database once, then fire 'select' query for once, and print me objects of std1 and std2 respectively.

## Instead i'm getting the error:

```
Feb 23, 2024 6:02:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.0.0.Final
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhCacheMessageLogger.<clinit>(EhCacheMessageLogger.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory.<clinit>(EhcacheRegionFactory.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:200)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.create(StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.create(StrategyCreatorRegionFactoryImpl.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.resolveRegionFactory(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:765)
    at com.SecondCache.SecondCacheExample.main(SecondCacheExample.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 35 more
```

**I also got this error at an instance**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2442)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1855)
    at com.example.hibernate.Hibernate4Main.main(Hibernate4Main.java:32)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:87)
    ... 10 more
```

"hibernate-core" and "mysql-connector-j" dependency has always been there in my pom, since i started learning hibernate.
When i began learning "Second Level Cache" i included new dependencies "hibernate-ehcache" and "ehcache"

I think there is a version conflict in the dependencies "hibernate-core" and "hibernate-ehcache".

Because of these new dependencies that i've added, all other programs that i've built till now(which are not even related with these new dependencies), while learning hibernate, are showing me the same error.

I also tried to learn about "Jcache", added "hibernate-jcache" dependency in pom file, added its classpath in hibernate-configuration-xml File, but still no results.

I've just started learning Hibernate and I'm facing difficulties to move further because of this issue. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thankyou!